# Ciclo For para la creación de tablas temporales dinámicas en PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, bucle-for, bucles

Qué tal?... Estoy elaborando un script en postgresql para la creación de tablas temporales dinámicas, tanto para el **nombre** de la tabla como para la condición **where a.estado=**. La siguiente query cumple con dicho objetivo, ya que reemplaza el string **('ACTIVO')** de la variable declarada nivel en la query que se inicializa con el begin.

```
DO $$
declare 
    nivel varchar := 'ACTIVO';
BEGIN
execute('drop table if exists cuentas_con_usuarios_'|| nivel ||
'; create temp table cuentas_con_usuarios_'|| nivel ||' AS (
SELECT * FROM usuario a WHERE a.estado = '''|| nivel  ||''')');
END$$
```

No obstante, el problema surge cuando quiero agregar el ciclo for para recorrer un array **['ACTIVO','OFF']** con la finalidad de que ejecuten independientemente ambas condiciones en la variable nivel. Logre avanzar esto:

```
      DO $$
      declare 
          i  varchar[];
          nivel varchar := array['ACTIVO','OFF'];   
     begin
        for i  in  nivel

        loop

       execute('drop table if exists cuentas_con_usuarios_'|| nivel ||
       '; create temp table cuentas_con_usuarios_'|| nivel ||' AS (
       SELECT * FROM usuario a WHERE a.estado = '''|| nivel  ||''')');

       end loop;
     END$$
```

El cual me señala el siguiente error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "nivel"
> LINE 8:   for i  in  nivel
> ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 230

Mi objetivo es que con una ejecución del script cree dos tablas temporales con nombre y condición where acorde a la lista del array **['ACTIVO','OFF']**. Este código lo requiero para un desarrollo con una base de mayor complejidad, pero si funciona con esta base ejemplo es suficiente:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuario
(usuario_id serial primary key, 
 usuario varchar(50), 
 estado varchar(7))

 ;


INSERT INTO usuario
(usuario_id, usuario, estado)
VALUES
(1, 'Pedro', 'ACTIVO'),
(2, 'Santiago', 'OFF'),
(3, 'Juna', 'ACTIVO')
```

Los leo,

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Debes inicializar la variable de tipo array con el arreglo de nombres y una variable auxiliar para recorrer ese arreglo.

En cada iteración, esta variable auxiliar contendrá el valor de cada elemento del arreglo.

Algo como:

```
  DO $$
  declare 
      niveles  varchar[] := array['ACTIVO','OFF'];   
      nivel    varchar;
 begin
   for nivel in niveles
   loop
     execute('drop table if exists cuentas_con_usuarios_'|| nivel ||
       '; create temp table cuentas_con_usuarios_'|| nivel ||' AS (
       SELECT * FROM usuario a WHERE a.estado = '''|| nivel  ||''')');
   end loop;
 END$$
```

En el ejemplo, `nivel` es la variable auxiliar con la que vamos recorriendo el arreglo `niveles`.

Answer (score 0):

Hola comunidad stackoverflow:
Tras darle vueltas y recibir ayuda, finalmente tengo la querie que me da los resultados deseados:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  i  varchar[];
  nivel varchar[] := array['ACTIVO','OFF'];   

BEGIN
 FOR i IN 1..array_length(nivel,1) LOOP
  EXECUTE('drop table if exists con_usuario_'|| nivel[i] ||
          '; create temp table  con_usuario_'|| nivel[i] ||' AS (
          SELECT * FROM usuario a WHERE a.estado = '''|| nivel[i]  ||''')');

 END LOOP;
END$$
```

Gracias por su apoyo.